# Selecting a div with jQuery based on multiple criteria found in child entities

Tags: jquery, html, selection, criteria

I have the following JQ code:

```
$("[class^=post],[href='/u1']").prev("div").css("background-color","blue");
$("[class^=post],[href='/u3']").prev("div").css("background-color","red");
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px">
<div id="p1" class="post row1">
    <div class="postprofile" id="profile44" style="height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <a href="/u1"><img src="/logo_1.png" alt=""></a>
            <strong style="font-size:1.2em">
<br />
                <a href="/u1">RD</a>
            </strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>...</dd>
        <dd>...</dd>
    </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="postbody" style="height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
        <div class="content-clearfix">
            <div>This is a test</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>

<br />


<div id="container2" style="width:500px">
<div id="p2" class="post row3">
    <div class="postprofile" id="profile45" style="height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <a href="/u3"><img src="/logo_2.png" alt=""></a>
            <strong style="font-size:1.2em">
<br />
                <a href="/u3">Evilyynn</a>
            </strong>
        </dt>
        <dd>...</dd>
        <dd>...</dd>
    </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="postbody" style="height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
        <div class="content-clearfix">
            <div>This is also a test</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I want to change the background colour of the postprofile div based on the href in a  tag, so that all /u1 hrefs have a red background and all /u3 have a blue background etc...

To the best of my knowledge the JQ code at the top is the easiest to do, however currently it selects all elements with a class starting with post OR a href of /u1 OR a href of /u3, so when I run it ALL the postprofile divs have a red background. 
How do I make it select all classes starting with post AND a href of /u1 or class starting with post AND a href of /u3

The JQ function is called when the HTML body loads.

Answer (score 2):

Your question deviates from your code, so I'll answer the following:

> How do I make it select all classes starting with post AND a href of /u1 or class starting with post AND a href of /u3

Use the context (second argument) on the selector to provide the context. In your selector, pass in a comma seperated list of target items.

```
$("a[href='/u1'], a[href='/u3']", "div[class^='post']").closest("div");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/FrYF7/

Or, following your initial code:

```
$("a[href='/u1']").closest("div[class^='post']").css("background", "blue");
$("a[href='/u3']").closest("div[class^='post']").css("background", "red");​
```

One other method would be to go straight for the div, and perform your background-color logic from within:

```
$("div[class^='post']").css("background", function(){
    if ( $("a[href='/u1']", this).length ) { 
        return "blue";
    } else if ( $("a[href='/u3']", this).length ) { 
        return "red";
    }
});​​​
```

Comment: If you read the question `.postprofile` is the targeted element. Also the partial class selector is overkill for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a starts-with selector for an element with multiple classes. `$("[class^=post]")` should just be `$(".post")`. Also the `,` in your selector will select both elements (the `a`, and the `div`). This is why it is selecting more elements than intended.

Use the [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) selector:

```
$("a[href='/u1']").parents("div.postprofile").css("background-color","blue");
$("a[href='/u3']").parents("div.postprofile").css("background-color","red");
```